# How to left adjust a linear program?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, align, alignat

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
  \begin{alignat*}{2}
    \text{minimize }   & \sum_{i=1}^m c_i x_i + \sum_{j=1}^n d_j t_j\  \\
    \text{subject to } & \sum_{i=1}^m a_{ij} + e_j t_j \geq g_j &,\ & 1\leq j\leq n\\
                       & f_i x_i + \sum_{j=1}^n b_{ij}t_j \geq h_i\ &,\ & 1\leq i\leq m\\
                       & x\geq 0,\ t_j\geq 0\ &,\ & 1\leq j\leq n,\ 1\leq i\leq m
  \end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Is recommended as a solution to generate the following linear program:

[image]

Unfortunately it is not exactly adjusted to be just under the heading there.

Can someone recommend a solution to left adjust this? I tried \left and changing that little number inside of \begin{alignat*}{} but it did not work...

Also there is a huge gap between the linear program (i.e. the code above) and whatever else you type outside of the code.

Example:

```
    {\bfseries Linear Program}

    Hello world:

     \begin{alignat*}{2}
     \text{minimize }   & \sum_{i=1}^m c_i x_i + \sum_{j=1}^n d_j t_j\  \\
     \text{subject to } & \sum_{i=1}^m a_{ij} + e_j t_j \geq g_j &,\ & 1\leq j\leq n\\
     & f_i x_i + \sum_{j=1}^n b_{ij}t_j \geq h_i\ &,\ & 1\leq i\leq m\\
     & x\geq 0,\ t_j\geq 0\ &,\ & 1\leq j\leq n,\ 1\leq i\leq m
     \end{alignat*}
This is a linear program
```

[image]

^Huge space cannot be removed by any means.

Can anyone fix that as well?

Comment: it is not clear (to me) what should be left adjusted? Your MWE doesn't contain `Linear programming`, where it should be?

Comment: @Zarko Oh just align that piece of code to the left, instead of centered as it is now

Comment: Don't leave blank line above `alignat*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

Instead `alignat` I use `flalign˙:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\textbf{Linear Program}
     \begin{flalign*}
\text{minimize }   & \sum_{i=1}^m c_i x_i 
                        + \sum_{j=1}^n d_j t_j\     &    \\
\text{subject to } & \sum_{i=1}^m a_{ij} 
                        + e_j t_j \geq g_j\ ,\quad 
                          1\leq j\leq n             &   \\
     & f_i x_i + \sum_{j=1}^n b_{ij}t_j \geq h_i\ ,\quad 
                        1\leq i\leq m\\
     & x\geq 0,\ t_j\geq 0\ ,\quad
       1\leq j\leq n,\ 1\leq i\leq m
     \end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```